# Android- Cannot Cast from View to Button

Tags: java, android, casting, android-button, findviewbyid

Okay, I'm new to both java and android programming, but I've come across the most frustrating error ever and I can't seem to be able to find the solution. here is where the error is at.

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_button);
```

And here is the XML of the button itself.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/button_text" />
```

I'm not seeing the problem, I imported `import com.awesometech.uselessbutton.R;` which didn't help. Any suggestions? I'm using Eclipse.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change to

```
 final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_main);
```

You have

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_main" // id is button_main not activity_button
```

Probably `activity_button` id belongs to another view and you are casting it to a `Button`.

Comment: I feel silly now, how did I miss that? I guess I was just tired.

Answer (score 0):

In your main Activity, in the `findViewbyId()` method, you pass the ID of your Button which you declared in you xml.

So your button code is :-

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="90dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:text="@string/button_text" />
```

here , id is button_main

so in you Class, you need to do

```
 final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_main);//Button ID goes here
```